# Facebook Invalid Scopes error on test app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

All of a sudden I'm getting an "Invalid Scopes: manage_pages" error during login in the **test version** of my Facebook app. 
The full error message is:

> Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

The live app is working fine.
Everything was working fine in the test app as well until this morning.

If I read the provided docs link it looks like *manage_pages* permission is still in use.

Anybody has an idea of what could be wrong with it?

Comment: Same issue here. Suddenly appeared today.

Comment: Same here.  Test apps are having a problem, prod apps are not.

Comment: Same here. The test apps are not showing up in the "Test app" panel neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was recently introduced. It's already been reported to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1605866199656679

As of 3 hours ago, it had been identified by Facebook engineering and a resolution should go live tonight (6-5-2015 PST). You can follow the status of the fix here: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/582921985181374/

Comment: @mettjus great! Could you please mark this as the answer to your question?